# print to console then create file and print console content into file

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

void GetOutputFileStream(std::ofstream * fout, std::string filename);
void PrintStatistics(std::ostream & fout,
int numUsed,
int numNew,
double newTotalPrice,
double newTotalMileage,
double usedTotalPrice,
double usedTotalMileage);

int main()
{


double newTotalPrice = 33333;
double newTotalMileage = 44444;
double usedTotalPrice = 22222;
double usedTotalMileage = 99999;
int numUsed = 2;
int numNew = 3;

std::ofstream fout; // 'f'ile out - fout
std::string filename = "statistics.txt";
GetOutputFileStream(&fout, filename);
// Print to screen
PrintStatistics(std::cout,
    numUsed,
    numNew,
    newTotalPrice,
    newTotalMileage,
    usedTotalPrice,
    usedTotalMileage);
// Print to file
PrintStatistics(fout,
    numUsed,
    numNew,
    newTotalPrice,
    newTotalMileage,
    usedTotalPrice,
    usedTotalMileage);



std::cout << "Press ENTER to continue";
std::cin.get();

return 0;
}

void GetOutputFileStream(std::ofstream * fout, std::string filename)
{
    fout->open(filename, std::ios::out);
}
void PrintStatistics(std::ostream & fout,
int numUsed,
int numNew,
double newTotalPrice,
double newTotalMileage,
double usedTotalPrice,
double usedTotalMileage)
{


}
```

I'm really stuck in this particular segment of an assignment where it requires me to print simple text into the console and then create a file (whatever std::string filename may be in main) and print the contents of the console into that file.

I'm really confused because the function requires ostream and it also requires the function to operate with any filename (it's statistics.txt in this example, just to test if the function is working).

The function is PrintStatistics.

I understand I can use cout to print onto the console and then I assume fout will print into the text file but that's not the case. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm new to this community so I hope my question makes sense/code is legible. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, `ofstream` is derived from the `ostream` system, allowing you to use `ofstream` anywhere that `ostream` is being used as well.

While I have not tested this, you should be able to get away while using your `fout` from the output file method, as your argument for the `ostream` parameter of your printing method.

Since `fout` is a derived version of `ostream`, the contents of the opened file and its data will be passed along with it, meaning if the argument for your `ostream` is an `fstream` type, it'll operate within the file instead of the console.

Comment: I use fout but it operates like cout. For example, I would use cout and fout sequentially in PrintStatistics but it prints both of fout and cout in the console and nothing in the file.

Thanks for taking the time to reply!

Comment: @alekbiz trying change your `GetOutputFileStream` method to call the printing method INSIDE after the opening of the file, see if that makes a difference. The way you have it now, there may be an issue with the scope of your `fout` and the operations on the file.

Comment: if you're referring to the code inside main() I cannot change that as it is specifically what the instructor is having us use to test our functions.

Comment: My mistake, I'm assuming you mean to re-work GetOutputFileStream, correct?

Comment: @alekbiz Yes, the `GetOutputFileStream` method itself, not main

Comment: I'm still a little confused as to how to reformat GetOutputFileStream, could you elaborate a little bit more? Sorry I'm new to streams and I'm having a difficult time

Answer (score 0):

It's more than usual to do such things in a wrapper around the application rater than inside the latter. Say,

```
<myApplication> <arguments> | tee <output_filename>
```

(in a Linux-like shell) will take the console output copy to a file.

Comment: what would the name of that method be? so I can look for some more information on it. thanks.